# Mejor forma de usar en un exec los campos obtenidos de una select

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Me surge la siguiente problematica.

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
Select Croqueta, Pimiento from Comidas
```

Y quiero usar el valor del campo "Croqueta" para pasarselo al procedimiento de la siguiente manera

```
exec Restaurante.Freidora @Croqueta=Croqueta
```

He visto que una de las maneras que se propone, es con una tabla temporal, pero me surge la duda de si no existe una manera más optima de hacerlo con SQL 2017

Comment: Quieres decir que la opción que mencionas no te funciona?

Comment: Si claro, lo que quiero decir es si existe una forma más optima de hacer esto. Cuánto mas optimo menos recursos usados y menos perdida de tiempo programando y menos posibilidades de errores.

Comment: Me parece que tu pregunta está basada en opiniones.

Comment: Me pregunta esta basada en experiencias de uso. Por eso uso busco el saber cuál es la manera más optima de hacerlo. Si tienes algo que aportar, agradeceria que aportaras tu experiencia

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer, requiere que se escriba un código más extenso para poder recorrer cada fila y usar el valor para ejecutar el procedimiento por cada valor. Para hacer eso, es necesario usar un ciclo muchas veces con la ayuda de un cursor.

```
DECLARE CurCroquetas CURSOR
LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT Croqueta
FROM Comidas;

DECLARE @croqueta varchar(100);
OPEN CurCroquetas;

FETCH NEXT FROM CurCroquetas INTO @croqueta;
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC Restaurante.Freidora @Croqueta=@Croqueta;

    FETCH NEXT FROM CurCroquetas INTO @croqueta;
END;

CLOSE CurCroquetas; 
DEALLOCATE CurCroquetas;
```

Desgraciadamente, este tipo de código no es óptimo y terminará generando un bajo rendimiento en el sistema. Lo ideal sería refactorizar el procedimiento para trabajar con todos los valores posibles en conjunto y no como valores escalares. Sin embargo, eso requiere otra pregunta con el código del procedimiento incluido.

Comment: Gracias @Luis Cazares, le voy a dar una vuelta a lo que me comentas y actualizare la pregunta